# std::experimental::is_detected with reference argument

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

With the following code:

```
#include <experimental/type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class A {};

class NoMember {};
class HasMember {
public:
    void doSomething(A &a) {
        std::cout << "Did something!\n";
    }
};

template<typename T, typename Arg>
using HasDoSomething = decltype(std::declval<T>().doSomething(std::declval<Arg>()));

template<typename T, typename Arg>
using CanDoSomething = std::experimental::is_detected<HasDoSomething, T, Arg>;

template<typename T, typename Arg, std::enable_if_t<CanDoSomething<T, Arg>::value> * = nullptr>
void TrySomething(T &t, Arg &arg) {
    t.doSomething(arg);
}

template<typename T, typename Arg, std::enable_if_t<!CanDoSomething<T, Arg>::value> * = nullptr>
void TrySomething(T &t, Arg &arg) {
    std::cout << "Did not do something\n";
}

int main(void) {
    A AnA;

    NoMember NoMem;
    HasMember Mem;

    TrySomething(NoMem, AnA);
    TrySomething(Mem, AnA);

    return 0;
}
```

I expected it to output:

```
Did not do something
Did something!
```

However, with g++ 8.2.0 it outputs:

```
Did not do something
Did not do something
```

I am guessing the problem is here:

```
template<typename T, typename Arg>
using HasDoSomething = decltype(std::declval<T().doSomething(std::declval<Arg>()));
```

Since `HasMember::doSomething` takes A by reference, it can't bind to the `declval<Arg>` "temporary."  Is that correct, or am I missing something else?

If it is correct, how does one use `is_detected` in the presence of reference arguments?

Comment: Your theory is correct. You just need to do `declval<Arg&>()` to make it return an lvalue.

Answer (score 3):

> Since `HasMember::doSomething` takes `A` by reference, it can't bind to the `declval<Arg>` "temporary." Is that correct, or am I missing something else?

That's right. `declval<U>()` returns a `U&&`. When `U=NonMem` this means an rvalue reference is passed in to `HasMember<T>::doSomething` which cannot bind to the lvalue reference in its parameter. Changing the template argument from `declval<Arg>()` to `declval<Arg&>()` will make the function return an lvalue instead (see [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing)).

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T, typename Arg, std::enable_if_t<CanDoSomething<T, Arg>::value> * = nullptr>
void TrySomething(T &t, Arg &arg) {
  t.doSomething(arg);
}
```

This asks "can I do (T&&).doSomething(Arg&&)`, where both`T`and`Arg` are rvalues.

```
template<typename T, typename Arg, std::enable_if_t<CanDoSomething<T&, Arg&>::value> * = nullptr>
void TrySomething(T &t, Arg &arg) {
  t.doSomething(arg);
}
```

this is what you want to ask.